# Could not find an ansible playbook when running script using supervisor

Tags: python-2.7, ansible, supervisord

I am relatively new to supervisord. I am trying to run my python script as a daemon process using supervisord. The following is my conf file which I put on `/etc/supervisor/conf.d`

```
[program:myscript]
command=/usr/bin/python /etc/supervisor/conf.d/main.py
user=ubuntu
autostart=true
autorestart=true
stderr_logfile=/var/log/stagingbot.err.log
stdout_logfile=/var/log/stagingbot.out.log
```

inside my `main.py`, there is a subprocess that will call an ansible playbook which is also located in `/etc/supervisor/conf.d`, named `start.yml`. However, I got an error saying that the particular yml could not be found.
`Error: the playbook: start.yml could not be found`

On the other hand, when I ran my script using `python main.py &` it works fine as it can find the ansible playbook.

any helps would be really appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try to chdir into that location?

```
[program:myscript]
command=/usr/bin/python /etc/supervisor/conf.d/main.py
directory=/etc/supervisor/conf.d
...
```

Comment: hey @udondan, thanks a lot. It perfectly works now after adding `directory=/etc/supervisor/conf.d`. Thanks a lot